# Can't locate File/Slurp.pm in @INC

Tags: linux, perl, uefi, xen

I'm trying to compile an [uefi application](https://github.com/tklengyel/xen-uefi) on Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS but the compilation terminates with an error.

```
./mkkeys.sh                    
Enter a Common Name to embed in the keys: keys
cc -I/home/jr/Downloads/xen-uefi/efitools/include/ -I/usr/include/efi -I/usr/include/efi/x86_64 -I/usr/include/efi/protocol -O2  -fpic -Wall -fshort-wchar -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-merge-constants -fno-stack-protector -ffreestanding -fno-stack-check -DGNU_EFI_USE_MS_ABI -DEFI_FUNCTION_WRAPPER -mno-red-zone -DCONFIG_x86_64 -c cert-to-efi-sig-list.c -o cert-to-efi-sig-list.o
cert-to-efi-sig-list.c:9: warning: "__STDC_VERSION__" redefined
    9 | #define __STDC_VERSION__ 199901L
      | 
<built-in>: note: this is the location of the previous definition
make -C lib lib.a
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/jr/Downloads/xen-uefi/efitools/lib'
cc -I/home/jr/Downloads/xen-uefi/efitools/include/ -I/usr/include/efi -I/usr/include/efi/x86_64 -I/usr/include/efi/protocol -O2  -fpic -Wall -fshort-wchar -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-merge-constants -fno-stack-protector -ffreestanding -fno-stack-check -DGNU_EFI_USE_MS_ABI -DEFI_FUNCTION_WRAPPER -mno-red-zone -DCONFIG_x86_64 -c simple_file.c -o simple_file.o
cc -I/home/jr/Downloads/xen-uefi/efitools/include/ -I/usr/include/efi -I/usr/include/efi/x86_64 -I/usr/include/efi/protocol -O2  -fpic -Wall -fshort-wchar -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-merge-constants -fno-stack-protector -ffreestanding -fno-stack-check -DGNU_EFI_USE_MS_ABI -DEFI_FUNCTION_WRAPPER -mno-red-zone -DCONFIG_x86_64 -c pecoff.c -o pecoff.o
cc -I/home/jr/Downloads/xen-uefi/efitools/include/ -I/usr/include/efi -I/usr/include/efi/x86_64 -I/usr/include/efi/protocol -O2  -fpic -Wall -fshort-wchar -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-merge-constants -fno-stack-protector -ffreestanding -fno-stack-check -DGNU_EFI_USE_MS_ABI -DEFI_FUNCTION_WRAPPER -mno-red-zone -DCONFIG_x86_64 -c guid.c -o guid.o
cc -I/home/jr/Downloads/xen-uefi/efitools/include/ -I/usr/include/efi -I/usr/include/efi/x86_64 -I/usr/include/efi/protocol -O2  -fpic -Wall -fshort-wchar -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-merge-constants -fno-stack-protector -ffreestanding -fno-stack-check -DGNU_EFI_USE_MS_ABI -DEFI_FUNCTION_WRAPPER -mno-red-zone -DCONFIG_x86_64 -c sha256.c -o sha256.o
cc -I/home/jr/Downloads/xen-uefi/efitools/include/ -I/usr/include/efi -I/usr/include/efi/x86_64 -I/usr/include/efi/protocol -O2  -fpic -Wall -fshort-wchar -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-merge-constants -fno-stack-protector -ffreestanding -fno-stack-check -DGNU_EFI_USE_MS_ABI -DEFI_FUNCTION_WRAPPER -mno-red-zone -DCONFIG_x86_64 -c console.c -o console.o
cc -I/home/jr/Downloads/xen-uefi/efitools/include/ -I/usr/include/efi -I/usr/include/efi/x86_64 -I/usr/include/efi/protocol -O2  -fpic -Wall -fshort-wchar -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-merge-constants -fno-stack-protector -ffreestanding -fno-stack-check -DGNU_EFI_USE_MS_ABI -DEFI_FUNCTION_WRAPPER -mno-red-zone -DCONFIG_x86_64 -c execute.c -o execute.o
cc -I/home/jr/Downloads/xen-uefi/efitools/include/ -I/usr/include/efi -I/usr/include/efi/x86_64 -I/usr/include/efi/protocol -O2  -fpic -Wall -fshort-wchar -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-merge-constants -fno-stack-protector -ffreestanding -fno-stack-check -DGNU_EFI_USE_MS_ABI -DEFI_FUNCTION_WRAPPER -mno-red-zone -DCONFIG_x86_64 -c configtable.c -o configtable.o
cc -I/home/jr/Downloads/xen-uefi/efitools/include/ -I/usr/include/efi -I/usr/include/efi/x86_64 -I/usr/include/efi/protocol -O2  -fpic -Wall -fshort-wchar -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-merge-constants -fno-stack-protector -ffreestanding -fno-stack-check -DGNU_EFI_USE_MS_ABI -DEFI_FUNCTION_WRAPPER -mno-red-zone -DCONFIG_x86_64 -c shell.c -o shell.o
cc -I/home/jr/Downloads/xen-uefi/efitools/include/ -I/usr/include/efi -I/usr/include/efi/x86_64 -I/usr/include/efi/protocol -O2  -fpic -Wall -fshort-wchar -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-merge-constants -fno-stack-protector -ffreestanding -fno-stack-check -DGNU_EFI_USE_MS_ABI -DEFI_FUNCTION_WRAPPER -mno-red-zone -DCONFIG_x86_64 -c security_policy.c -o security_policy.o
cc -I/home/jr/Downloads/xen-uefi/efitools/include/ -I/usr/include/efi -I/usr/include/efi/x86_64 -I/usr/include/efi/protocol -O2  -fpic -Wall -fshort-wchar -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-merge-constants -fno-stack-protector -ffreestanding -fno-stack-check -DGNU_EFI_USE_MS_ABI -DEFI_FUNCTION_WRAPPER -mno-red-zone -DCONFIG_x86_64 -c shim_protocol.c -o shim_protocol.o
cc -I/home/jr/Downloads/xen-uefi/efitools/include/ -I/usr/include/efi -I/usr/include/efi/x86_64 -I/usr/include/efi/protocol -O2  -fpic -Wall -fshort-wchar -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-merge-constants -fno-stack-protector -ffreestanding -fno-stack-check -DGNU_EFI_USE_MS_ABI -DEFI_FUNCTION_WRAPPER -mno-red-zone -DCONFIG_x86_64 -c pkcs7verify.c -o pkcs7verify.o
cc -I/home/jr/Downloads/xen-uefi/efitools/include/ -I/usr/include/efi -I/usr/include/efi/x86_64 -I/usr/include/efi/protocol -O2  -fpic -Wall -fshort-wchar -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-merge-constants -fno-stack-protector -ffreestanding -fno-stack-check -DGNU_EFI_USE_MS_ABI -DEFI_FUNCTION_WRAPPER -mno-red-zone -DCONFIG_x86_64 -c kernel_efivars.c -o kernel_efivars.o
kernel_efivars.c:19: warning: "__STDC_VERSION__" redefined
   19 | #define __STDC_VERSION__ 199901L
      | 
<built-in>: note: this is the location of the previous definition
kernel_efivars.c: In function ‘kernel_variable_init’:
kernel_efivars.c:61:2: warning: ignoring return value of ‘read’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
   61 |  read(fd, buf, st.st_size);
      |  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
kernel_efivars.c: In function ‘get_variable’:
kernel_efivars.c:107:2: warning: ignoring return value of ‘read’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
  107 |  read(fd, &attr, sizeof(attr));
      |  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
kernel_efivars.c:113:3: warning: ignoring return value of ‘read’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
  113 |   read(fd, buf, st.st_size - sizeof(attr));
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
ar rcv lib.a simple_file.o pecoff.o guid.o sha256.o console.o execute.o configtable.o shell.o security_policy.o shim_protocol.o pkcs7verify.o kernel_efivars.o
a - simple_file.o
a - pecoff.o
a - guid.o
a - sha256.o
a - console.o
a - execute.o
a - configtable.o
a - shell.o
a - security_policy.o
a - shim_protocol.o
a - pkcs7verify.o
a - kernel_efivars.o
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/jr/Downloads/xen-uefi/efitools/lib'
cc  -o cert-to-efi-sig-list cert-to-efi-sig-list.o -lcrypto lib/lib.a
cc -I/home/jr/Downloads/xen-uefi/efitools/include/ -I/usr/include/efi -I/usr/include/efi/x86_64 -I/usr/include/efi/protocol -O2  -fpic -Wall -fshort-wchar -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-merge-constants -fno-stack-protector -ffreestanding -fno-stack-check -DGNU_EFI_USE_MS_ABI -DEFI_FUNCTION_WRAPPER -mno-red-zone -DCONFIG_x86_64 -c sign-efi-sig-list.c -o sign-efi-sig-list.o
sign-efi-sig-list.c:7: warning: "__STDC_VERSION__" redefined
    7 | #define __STDC_VERSION__ 199901L
      | 
<built-in>: note: this is the location of the previous definition
sign-efi-sig-list.c: In function ‘main’:
sign-efi-sig-list.c:163:3: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘strptime’; did you mean ‘strftime’? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  163 |   strptime(timestampstr, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", &tms);
      |   ^~~~~~~~
      |   strftime
sign-efi-sig-list.c:221:2: warning: ignoring return value of ‘read’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
  221 |  read(fdefifile, ptr, st.st_size);
      |  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
sign-efi-sig-list.c:244:3: warning: ignoring return value of ‘read’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
  244 |   read(infile, sigbuf, sigsize);
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
sign-efi-sig-list.c:316:2: warning: ignoring return value of ‘write’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
  316 |  write(fdoutfile, out, outlen);
      |  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
sign-efi-sig-list.c:319:3: warning: ignoring return value of ‘write’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
  319 |   write(fdoutfile, ptr, st.st_size);
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
make -C lib lib.a
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/jr/Downloads/xen-uefi/efitools/lib'
make[1]: 'lib.a' is up to date.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/jr/Downloads/xen-uefi/efitools/lib'
cc  -o sign-efi-sig-list sign-efi-sig-list.o -lcrypto lib/lib.a
Generating a RSA private key
..........................................+++++
.......................................................................................................+++++
writing new private key to 'PK.key'
-----
Generating a RSA private key
....................................+++++
....................................................................................................+++++
writing new private key to 'KEK.key'
-----
Generating a RSA private key
..................+++++
...........................................................+++++
writing new private key to 'DB.key'
-----
Generating a RSA private key
.............+++++
..................................................+++++
writing new private key to 'SHIM.key'
-----
Timestamp is 2021-9-23 15:55:51
Authentication Payload size 861
Signature of size 1182
Signature at: 40
Timestamp is 2021-9-23 15:55:51
Authentication Payload size 865
Signature of size 1182
Signature at: 40
Timestamp is 2021-9-23 15:55:51
Authentication Payload size 861
Signature of size 1185
Signature at: 40
Timestamp is 2021-9-23 15:55:52
Authentication Payload size 40
Signature of size 1182
Signature at: 40
make -C lib lib.a
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/jr/Downloads/xen-uefi/efitools/lib'
make[1]: 'lib.a' is up to date.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/jr/Downloads/xen-uefi/efitools/lib'
./xxdi.pl PK.auth > PK.h
Can't locate File/Slurp.pm in @INC (you may need to install the File::Slurp module) (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.30.0 /usr/local/share/perl/5.30.0 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.30 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.30 /usr/share/perl/5.30 /usr/local/lib/site_perl /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl-base) at ./xxdi.pl line 17.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at ./xxdi.pl line 17.
make: *** [Make.rules:69: PK.h] Error 2
```

What am I doing wrong? Do I need to install perl? which perl in terminal returns the directory in which perl is installed. Does this mean perl isn't the issue? I don't know what other details to give but if someone could point me in the right direction I would really appreciate it.

Comment: First logical step would be to check if your system has `Slurp.pm` file available. If it is then it is a matter to modify variable `@INC`. If `Slurp.pm` is not available on your system then it is a matter of installing required package `apt-get install libfile-slurp-perl libperl6-slurp-perl`. It would be not a bad idea to add to your question output of `perl -v` .

Comment: `libperl6-slurp-perl` is Perl6::Slurp, which is a completely different module. Just `apt-get install libfile-slurp-perl`.

Answer (score 5):

Perl comes with a large number of standard libraries that extend its capabilities. But there are thousands of other extension libraries available from [CPAN](https://metacpan.org/).

[File::Slurp](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Slurp) is a CPAN module. It's not part of the standard Perl distribution, so you'll need to install it separately.

Fortunately, Ubuntu packages up a huge number of CPAN modules and make them available from their standard repositories. So, to install it, you just have to run:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libfile-slurp-perl
```